# CAN FD controller + classic CAN transceiver

Tags: can

I'm currently designing a CAN network that will use a long bus (500 m), so the communication speed won't exceed 50 kbps. Also, I want to use the CAN FD capability to send large 64 byte payload messages.

I've heard that using CAN FD transceivers for long networks is not optimal due to the steep FD signal slopes that cause extra ringing in long networks with stubs (no matter what baudrate is used).

So the idea is to use an FD controller to utilize the protocol features like large packets, but a slow classic CAN 2.0 transceiver with slower signal slopes.

Will it work? Can CAN 2.0 transceivers work with FD controllers in FD mode (within allowed baudrate limit)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing bitrate switch BRS (that is supported by FD) with FD itself.

A classic controller receiving an FD frame will trigger an error frame, since the bit sequence on the bus does not make sense to it.

However, you are NOT forced to change bitrate with FD - but if you transmit an FD frame, all the controllers (not transceivers, which are basically voltage translators!) MUST be CAN FD. You can definitely use a single baudrate with CAN FD at 50 kbit/s.

Comment: To sum up, will a classic CAN transceiver work fine with an FD controller with FD frames? Moreover will it work with BRS as long as I don't exceed 1Mbps baudrate in data phase?

Comment: @AleksY If all the node *controllers* are CAN FD, and you only use classical CAN *transceivers* (the stupid version like NXP TJA1040T or Microchip MCP2561, not things like SPI ones), they will work up to 1 Mbps (though given your topology I would not dare to go so fast - unless you are using SIC transceivers). Transceivers and topology limit speed, controllers dictate supported frame formats. If you have even a single classical *controller* in the network, you HAVE to use ONLY classical frames (beware that FD frame with payload <= 8 byte is still different from classical one).

Comment: @AleksY if you take a classical transceiver like TJA1040T and an FD transceiver like TJA1042T, you can see that slopes are comparable. An FD transceiver will not cause ringing, and if it is SIC will cause LESS ringing than a classical one.